# How to update brokered message output properties in node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am writing an azure function in node.js which outputs a service bus message. How can I set the values of the brokered message such as ContentType, ReplyTo and custom properties? It seems like I can only set the message body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot via output binding in node.

As you need more control, I'd recommend using the service bus node sdk to create and send the sb messages inside your function instead of an output binding.

If you prefer the binding model, you could use C# which supports richer output types.